# Unable to compile PIL/pysqlite after OS X 10.7 Lion upgrade

Tags: python, xcode4, python-imaging-library, pysqlite

After Lion upgrade, I had to reinstall my python packages, and ran into problem installing PIL and pysqlite.

```
...
unable to execute gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is it is late, but I couldn't figure this out for the last few hours.. I'm posting my easy fix in case anyone else runs into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out all I had to do was link up gcc-4.2, which was in /Developer/usr/bin

I added `export PATH=$PATH:/Developer/usr/bin` to ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 2):

ln -s /Developer/usr/bin/gcc /Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2

Comment: ln: /Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2: No such file or directory